# Show gmaps location when clicking on an item (Gmaps4rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Im trying to add some callback to my code, so when clicking on a picture outside the map, the maps get centered to the position that image contains, so I try this.

```
Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
  var event = document.getElementsByClassName("link-s");
  event.onclick = showEvent;

  function showEvent(pos) {
    var pos = -25.363882,131.044922;
    Gmaps4Rails.map.setCenter(pos.latLng);
  };
};
```

it doesnt throw any error, im using "pos" for testing purposes, but i cant make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a question of javascript:

```
Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
  var events = document.getElementsByClassName("link-s");

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; ++i) {
    events[i].onclick = function() { showEvent(); };
  }

  function showEvent() {
    Gmaps4Rails.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922));
  };
}
```